# Noob question: Trying to censor specific words in a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm a noob and am on chapter 4 of this c++ book and I can't answer this assignment correctly.

The code that makes sense to me but doesn't work is included down below.

Here is the assignment:

Write a program that “bleeps” out words that you don’t like; that is, you read in words using cin and print them again on cout. If a word is among a few you have defined, you
write out BLEEP instead of that word. Start with one “disliked word” such as
string disliked = “Broccoli”;
When that works, add a few more.

Help would be greatly appreciated, I might even mail you some cookies.

```
int main() {

vector<string> words;

for (string temp; cin >> temp; )

    words.push_back(temp);

string disliked = "broccoli";

for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)

    if (words[i] == disliked ||  disliked=="Bleep!")

        cout << words[i] << "\n";
```

Even if I type in several words all I get out ironically is "broccoli" and nothing else.

Comment: This is an excellent place to use a debugger. Step through your code in a debugger and watch what happens.

Comment: `all I get out ironically is "broccoli"` - that's all you ask for, as far as I can see (since `disliked` can never become "Bleep1" here).

Comment: You're explicitly checking that words[i] is "broccoli" and only print it if it is.

Comment: You can use this `words[i] != disliked ? cout << words[i] << "\n" : cout<< "Bleep!\n";`

Comment: `unordered_set<std::string> banned{"bleach", "smurf"};  
auto [it, got_lucky] = banned.emplace(word);`

Comment: Unrelated: You can use a [ranged-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to simplify your code a little. eg: `for (auto & word: words) { if (word ==  disliked) { do stuff} }` Going a bit further [you could use `std::replace_if(words.begin(), words.end(), disliked, "Bleep!");` to do almost all of the work for you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)

Answer (score 4):

The reason it's only printing out "broccoli" is because of these lines here:

```
    if (words[i] == disliked ||  disliked=="Bleep!")

        cout << words[i] << "\n";
```

These lines essentially mean "if the word equals broccoli, print out that word". The second part of the check, `disliked == "Bleep!"`, is always false (because `disliked` is always "broccoli"), so it doesn't play a role.

We can fix things like this:

```
include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<string> words;

    for (string temp; cin >> temp;)

        words.push_back(temp);

    string disliked = "broccoli";

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)

        if (words[i] == disliked)

            cout << "Bleep!" << '\n';
        else 
            cout << words[i] << '\n'; 
}
```

Here, the logic is "if the word is disliked, print out "Bleep", otherwise, print out the word."

If you have any more questions, I'd be happy to answer them, and any cookies would definitely be appreciated! :)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. If words[i]==disliked then it will cout "bleep!", else it will cout the other words. Cookies coming your way my friend, just don't complain if they're a little moldy. Also might get a hungry post office guy or gal willing to snatch 'em.

Comment: Thank you haha XD

Answer (score 1):

What justin say is true. A debugger could show you exactly what happen by following line by line what happen (your program is little enough to do that).

However i will answer. Here the problem comes from the line

```
if (words[i] == disliked ||  disliked=="Bleep!")
```

You test if the word is the disliked one and you show it. So yes, there is only broccoli. By the way you don't exactly follow what your exercise say, since you should cout bleep when the word is disliked and cout the word if not. (according to what i understand).

Hope it helps.